# java.lang.AssertionError throwing null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit4

We have created test for the functionality via `springframework.test.context.junit4`.

Below is one of the test case :

**Test Class**

```
  @Test
    public void testAuthorizedPut() throws Exception {
        ThreadContext.bind(subject);
        when(subject.isPermitted(getPlural() + ":put")).thenReturn(true);
        when(subject.isPermitted(getPlural() + ":get")).thenReturn(true);
        assertThat(adminTemplate().exchange(getTestHost() + "/api/1/" + getPlural() + "/45454-67567d-f5224666a9", HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<Object>(getInstance(),getStandardHeaders()),entityClass).getBody(), equalTo(getInstance()));
    }
```

When code move to resource class that are used to mock. Like for above test code will move to PUT request of resources :

**MyResource Class**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Update MyResource definition", notes = "Enter the id of the MyResource definition, returns updated MyResource definition", response = MyResource.class)
    @Path("/{id}")
    @PUT
    @Timed
    @Override
    public MyResource update(@PathParam("id") String id, MyResource newInstance) {
        return super.update(id, newInstance);          
    }
```

When we run the test written above **testAuthorizedPut** then it throw below error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <MyResource(id=null, metadataTemplate=null, name=null, shortLabel=null, description=null, embedInObject=false, optional=false, type=null, possibleValues=null)>
     but: was null
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
    at org.openskye.resource.AbstractUpdatableResourceTestBase.testAuthorizedPut(AbstractUpdatableResourceTestBase.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
```

BUT when I write resource class PUT as, means return newInstance separate solve the above error:

```
 public MyResource update(@PathParam("id") String id, MyResource newInstance) {
            super.update(id, newInstance);  
            return newInstance;        
        }
```

So what is the difference of returning newInstance with super calls OR separate call. How can this error resolved without above changes?

Answer (score 1):

code from inherited Update() method would be apreciated.
And, well, you return recieved object from method in one case and in the second you return object from method parameter in that same method.
And the answer to your question lies in super.update() blackBox.

For all I know it could be

```
    MyResource update(){
        return null;
    }
```

and this would explain the output. You should inspect why super.update returned null.